# Typescript: Is it possible to have a React.Component as a type?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have the following structure:

```
export abstract class SomeAbstractClass extends React.Component<any,any>{
    protected abstract menuItems: MenuItem[];
}
```

Now I want to implement the `menuItems` in the implementing class e.g.

```
this.menuItems = [<MenuItem/>]; // test purpose it has no props
```

But the compiler complains

> Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'MenuItem'.
>       Property 'setState' is missing in type 'Element'.

How can I make this work? Where does `setState` come from? If I use `any` as a type it works just fine.

The typing looks like this while `MenuItemProps` is a bunch of optional fields.

```
 export class MenuItem extends React.Component<MenuItemProps, {}> {
 }
```

It's from the Material-UI library [source](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/menu).

I am using Typescript 2.1.5

Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

You a mixing here two different concepts.

First is how and what you declare for the react to render. 
For example if you write:

```
render()
{
    return <MenuItem/>
}
```

All you do is instruct react to somehow create object of type MenuElement and render it. Note - you do not declare nor create any instance of MenuItem here. You only describe what you want to archive.

Second is react itself that takes your "description" and converts it into actual JS code that browser can run and create your described behavior.

When writing

```
this.menuItems = [<MenuItem/>]
```

React will converts it to something like this:

```
this.menuItems = [React.createElement(MenuItem)]
```

As you can see there is not instance of `MenuItem` created yet.

If you do want to work with instances of your components you can do that but at much later stage (see [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) more info)

You should try not to "store" elements (like `<MenuItem>`) outside of render. And create them only when you want to describe your required structure. Instead in your this.menuItems field you should store the data that will later during render phase will help you to declare necessary component structure.

Comment: I understand that. In the end it will be inside the `render` method, but it seems like I can not use `MenuItem` as a type. It will work if I change it to `JSX.Element[]` or `React.ReactNode[]` for example.

Comment: You can use it, form example `this.menuItems = [MenuItem]`. Just do not write `<MenuItem/>` because that will  get converted to totally different class instance, as you correctly mentioned